# zendframework large query, please advice on the best solution

Tags: zend-framework2

I need some advice please, I have been looking for help on this topic but it's not something you find so often.  I am also quite new to Zend, so please excuse my terminology

I have a few large sql queries coming up.  Most of my other queries are quite small, just a couple of joins etc, but these ones consist of many queries (drop and create temporary tables which together form the final select.) For example

```
DROP table if exists tmp_abc;
CREATE temporary table tmp_abc as SELECT .... From ... Group By //finish statement
```

Consider 20 other of these, then a final select which pulls a lot of data from one table.

Can anyone offer some advice on the best solution to tackle this problem?

Would this be possible using some RAW sql adapter or? ... I am kinda of tempted to sod the MVC principle for this based on the complexity/size of the query, but it is something I would like to know for the future which action I should go.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to do most of it on database level, some stored procedure(s)/maybe view or two if needed. And then select from that.

Comment: Maybe I can look into creating a SP for it.  Open for more suggestions.